# I am not able to assign value to this variable in mongoose schema

Tags: mongoose, schema

I am new to Node.js mongo.so I am having some difficulty assigning the value to the variable in the schema. Please help.

My schema is something like this:

```
var userschema = mongoose.Schema({
    email:String,
    password:String,
    add:String,
    question:[String,],
    ans:[
        {
            title:String,
        }
    ]
})
```

I am accessing like this:

```
 var m = new User;

 m.email='myid@gmail.com';

 m.password='something';

 m.add='mmj';

 m.question.push('mman'); 

 m.ans[0].title='something';
```

Comment: I am accessing like this:-   var m = new User;
m.email='myid@gmail.com',
m.password='something',
m.add='mmj',
m.question.push('mman');
m.ans[0].title='something';

Answer (score 0):

A couple of pointers:

> var m = new User;

will not work, you'll need to call the constructor User() like this

```
var m = new User(); // also, use 'let' or 'const' instead of 'var' if possible
```

> m.ans[0].title='something';

Will not work, you'll have to initialize the element first. Something like this:

```
m.ans[0] = {};
m.ans[0].title = 'something';
```

or even

```
m.ans.push({title: 'something'});
```

Alternatively, you can also directly call User like this:

```
const m = new User({
    email: 'myid@gmail.com',
    password: 'something',
    add: 'mmj',
    question: ['mman'],
    ans: ['something'],
})
```

If it still won't work, please post more information on the problem you're having. E.g. error-logs.

Comment: No problem, please upvote and select this post as the correct answer, if it solved your problem.

Comment: Need your help once again . I want to access the array inside ans array

Comment: someArray[0][0].someField?